# Does Visual Studio Hijack R-Studio's CRAN Repository?

Tags: r, visual-studio, rstudio

I recently installed MS Visual Studio and permitted it to include R development.

However, when I went back to my R Studio environment, I found that I had to reinstall all my packages.

Worse, when I tried to run my old scripts the function `funion` was no longer recognized.  Since `funion` is in the `data.table` package (or at least *was*) I did a grep on the downloaded package source for `funion` and it wasn't found.

Then I noticed something suspicious:

The version number was *way* behind CRAN and [the URL from which `data.table` was downloaded](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-11-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/data.table_1.9.6.zip) wasn't CRAN but apparently some site supplying MS versions of R packages.

Is it my imagination, or is MS not only hijacking the downloading of packages, but then providing packages that are way out of date and/or lacking major functions?

Comment: If you've installed MRO, MRAN is a feature, not a bug. You should still be able to set `.libPaths()` and your CRAN mirror, though.

Comment: What I'd really like to do is undo the damage done by Visual Studio.  I ran the Visual Studio installer and removed R support, but that didn't revert the change to the URL.  Moreover, the directions given to set the CRAN mirror URL pointed me to the wrong file to edit.  The MRAN URL isn't in that file.  Must I simply reinstall R Studio to undo the damage?  https://www.r-bloggers.com/permanently-setting-the-cran-repository/

Comment: I ran `chooseCRANmirror()` and that seems to have permitted me to do a valid `install.packages("data.table")` once I chose a CRAN mirror.

Comment: The issue isn't about VS or RStudio, it's about the R installation each is running. VS installed MRO (which defaults to MRAN instead of CRAN) for you instead of CRAN R.

Comment: If that is the case, why did the R installation (seem to) change for RStudio when VS installed MRO for its R installation?

Comment: Because both IDEs use the same language binary for R—whichever version they find on `$PATH`. VS installed a new one (MRO), which therefore changed the one RStudio found. The old installation may still be there further down `$PATH`.